# How should I handle follow-on questions to a bounty question?

Tags: discussion, bounties, etiquette

In [What kind of computer is being used in “Workin on ur problemz”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz), the question I actually asked has been answered (V-Tech Talking Whiz Kid Mouse PRO Deluxe), but there's something else that I'd still like to know (why is there a piece of paper in front of the monitor?). (I mentioned the piece of paper before setting the bounty in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz/37640#37640) but not in the question)

Should I

1. Have thought more carefully about my question before setting a bounty to it
2. Accept the answer given, but edit the question (which'd attract fewer eyes)
3. Hold out on awarding the bounty until the follow-on question is answered (is that fair on the bounty-hunter?)
4. Start a new question about the paper
5. Get a life (who cares about the paper?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1 and #4**

They're separate questions; if you do #2, the bounty-accepted isn't going to answer the new; if you do #3, not fair to the existing bounty-hunter.

#5, is of course, not an acceptable option.

Comment: +1 for the comment on #5.